# What is the "cost" of computation of two special CAS algorithms

Tags: elementary-number-theory, polynomials, computer-algebra-systems

Suppose I have an integer $n$ with e.g. a large number of say decimal digits.

I would like to get some information about the runtime "cost" of standard CAS algorithm which factors $n$ into primes in comparison to the CAS algorithm which decomposes a polynomial of degree $n$ into irreducible factor polynomials.

Which problem is faster solved ?

Comment: You might start by looking up "factorization" on Wikipedia.

Comment: I found http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factorization and therein the remark "The more classical hand techniques rely on either the polynomial to be factored having low degree or the recognition of the polynomial as belonging to a certain class of known examples and are not very suitable for computer implementation. This article is concerned with these classical techniques." But I am interested in CAS techniques - not the manual methods.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factorization_of_polynomials#Modern_methods

Comment: If you factor $\sum_{k=0}^n d_kX^k$, you get a factorization of $\sum_{k=0}^n d_k10^k$ for free (though some factors like $X-9$ might lead to trivial factors of the latter)

Comment: I think you are right with this convincing argument.